# FB Graph API: Get id of a page with a country restriction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the Page ID of a page that has country restrictions?

Usually if I do something like `http://graph.facebook.com/google`

I'll get a response object with a bunch of info (incl. the id).

However doing `http://graph.facebook.com/[page_with_country_restriction]` returns:

```
{
    "error": {
       "message": "Unsupported get request.",
       "type": "GraphMethodException",
       "code": 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's possible to get the information of a page with country restrictions. You just need a valid [Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) for that.

Try making a request to the URL using that Access Token. Something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/teabeauty?access_token={Access_Token}
```

You can always make use of [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=google) to test your requests and queries.